# Exact area using limits and Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, problem-solving

the i need to find the exact area under tha curve of the function $f(x)=4+3x-x^2$ on the interval $[-1,3]$ using limits and a Riemann Sum. I have nothing started, because I am confused on where to start, and where I would need to go from there, I need help with the entire problem. I hope someone can help me! Thanks

Comment: I guess you mean the are in the region limited between the function's two roots and the $\,x-$axis...?

Comment: yea i forgot to put it, on the interval [-1,3]

Comment: Well, the roots are $\,-1\,,\,4\;$ so I suppose in the interval $\,[-1,4]\;$ ...?

Comment: no, it is [-1,3]

Comment: Then it is *not* the area between the function's roots and the $\,x-$axis...ok.

Comment: no i see what you are saying i think. it is the area under the curve of that function..... sorry my wording was very poor...

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas for you to understand, prove and develop:

$$f(x)=-x^2+3x+4$$

and since this is a continuous and thus integrable function in any finite interval, we can choose now  partitions of the interval $\,[-1,3]\;$ and choose conveniently the points within each subinterval in each partition, say:

$$\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;;\;\;P_n:=\left\{x_0:=-1\,,\,x_1:=-1+\frac4n\,,\,x_2:=-1+\frac8n\,,\ldots\,,\,x_n=-1+\frac{4n}n=3\right\}$$

and we choose conveniently in each subinterval

$$c_k=\left(-1+\frac{4k}n\right)\in [x_{k-1},x_k]\;,\;k=1,2,\ldots,n$$

so we get the Riemann sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^nf(c_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})=\frac4n\sum_{k=1}^n\left[-\left(-1+\frac{4k}n\right)^2+3\left(-1+\frac{4k}n\right)+4\right]=$$

$$=\frac4n\sum_{k=1}^n\left[-\frac{16k^2}{n^2}+\frac{20k}n\right]=\frac{16}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(-4k^2+5nk\right)=$$

$$\frac{16}{n^3}\left(-4\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+5n\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)=$$

$$=-\frac{32}3\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{n^3}+40\frac{n^2(n+1)}{n^3}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\ldots?$$

Comment: so the answer is just sloving for the last part? and for n i plug in the number of rectangles under that graph? correct

Comment: No. The answer is *to justify* each step, from the claims about continuity and integrability through particular choice of the partition and each point in the subinterval and until the summatories.

Comment: Interesting why somebody found it fit to downvote this answer...or perhaps it is, again, the serial downvoter? Oh, well...

Comment: well i am supposed to find the exact area under the graph, without using limits and a riemann sum, not integration. i just posted another question that i am supposed to do it with integration, i'm super lost in my calculus class, and need help with this assignment that is due tomorrow, then i have my final tuesday

Comment: and i did not downvote you! this helps me out a little bit

Comment: No @cschurman, **you wrote** you have to calculate the area *with* limits and Riemann sums! And if you're that lost it may be a good idea to ask for some help to your lecturer/instructor as here you can get some light, quick explanations, not more than that.

Comment: the question says, "find the exact area under the curve of the function f(x)=4+$3x$-$x^2$ using limits (not integration) and a riemann sum, that is what the question on my paper reads....

Comment: Ok, then the above is what you need: the last limit gives you *the exact* area...etc.

Comment: what numbers do i plug in for n? because i need a final answer with no variables

Comment: you don't "plug" numbers for $\,n\,$, @cschurman : you evaluate the limit, that's all.

Comment: i'm sitll lost. to evaluate the limit, where do i need to go next?